# Can I get iPhone-like folders on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu, and my desktop is getting very messy. Most people organize things in folders, but I don't like opening up a whole window to access my stuff. I like the way iPods (and OS X Lion's Launchpad) have folders: The content shows up right by the folder. You don't have to move your mouse very far to get to the content in a folder.

I also like the way you can put a folder in the dock on Macs. Click on the folder and its content appears right above, and if you want to navigate to a subfolder, just click on the folder in the popup, and it will show the content of a subfolder.

What I would like to know is if there is anything like this for Linux, or any other program that could organize my desktop like this.

ipad folder:

[image]

A folder in a Mac dock:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the closest thing that exists to what you want is: [Glx-Dock / Cairo-Dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/).

[image]

[image]

Here are the [instructions for installing on Ubuntu](http://www.glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=From%20the%20repository&lang=en).